# How can i hide the nonce value in a script tag

Tags: html

In my script tag I add a nonce value `<script nonce="xxxxxx">.....</script>`.
In the CSP `script-src 'nonce-xxxxxx';`
But I'd like to hide the nonce value when I inspect the code

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you don't need to.

Since the allowed value for the nonce is generated at the same time as the CSP header, an attacker can't inject HTML containing the nonce into the document because there is no way for them to know what it is in time.

Answer (score -1):

If it must be in the script tag when you start you can just store it in a variable and then remove the `nonce` attribute from the script tag. Otherwise you can just define it for example as `var nonce = "your-nonce-here";

Although I don't exactly know why you'd want to hide it from your inspect-code, do keep in mind that if a malicious person wants to get that nonce, it wouldn't be too difficult to get with the console or just by adding debug points in the code.

Comment: The point is to protect my application. But i don't know the good pratice for a good CSP parameter  for sript

Comment: If it isn't set as an attribute of the script tag then it won't work.

Comment: A nonce generally is against replay attacks, which are attacks where an attacker tries to send the exact same info as you to try to login for example. And since that nonce is "used" after the first time it can't be used again. And it's okay for a nonce to be visible to the user. The nonce is only useful in the context of that user, and having it visible doesn't jeopardise the safety of other users.